# object issues of javascript

Tags: javascript

I constructed a function defined as

```
var Func1 = function() 
{
    return {
             alert: function() { alert( "Lady Gaga" ); }
           };
};
```

And I assigned `Func1()` to a variable, like this:

```
var func1 = Func1();
```

I found something make no sense to me that `Func1()` created an object for func1 although I didn't put the `new` in front of it.

Isn't that objects could only be created by `new`?

What happened when the expression above is being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a javascript literal object (json like), it's the equivalent to create a new object with the new operator and assign its properties.

This

```
var a = { test: 123, caca: 'pipi' };
```

Is the same as

```
var a = new Object();

a.test = 123;
a.caca = 'pipi';
```

Comment: Object literals are not JSON. Also the two examples given are not the same because the resulting objects will have different prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't need the new keyword. The above code assigned the return value to the newly created func1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are returning from `Func1`:

```
return {
    alert: function() { alert( "Lady Gaga" ); }
};
```

You return an object, and that object is assigned to `func1`. So `func1 = Func1();` simply calls `Func1`, and assigns the result of that to `func1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is creating an object with:

```
{
    alert: function() { alert( "Lady Gaga" ); }
};
```

Using that notation, there's no need to use the `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The () actually executes the function, which returns an object with a method (a method is a property of type function).

In JS, you don't explicitly call `new` to create new objects:

```
var song = {
  name: "Entrenched",
  artist: "Morbid Angel"
};

song.artist = "Bolt Thrower";
```

This creates an object with the properties `name` and `artist`.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword used with a function is one way to create an object, but not the only way. It means that a new object will be created with the specified function called as a constructor - within the constructor the `this` keyword will reference the new object, and the new object will be returned. Call the same function without the `new` keyword and an object will not be created.

The object literal syntax (e.g., `var x = { };` or `return { };`) is another way to create an object.